# Generics where you already know the type of the generic type?

Tags: java, generics, conventions

Given the following interface:

```
Interface Executor<T extends Form>
{
   public Result execute( Request<T> request);
}
```

as well as a number of implementations of this interface, such as:

- `LoginExecutor`,
- `AddContactExecutor`, etc.

For each implementation, I know exactly what the value of `T` is going to be.

E.g, for `LoginExecutor`, `T` will be `LoginForm extends Form`, etc.

What's the conventional way of defining my implementations in such a case? If I do:

```
public LoginExecutor<LoginForm> implements Executor<LoginForm>
{
   public Result execute(LoginForm request) {...}
}
```

that gives me an error. So I'm doing the following:

```
public LoginExecutor<T extends LoginForm> implements Executor<T>
{
   public Result execute(T request) {...}
}
```

and that seems to be working, however I'm wondering if there is a a better / more conventional way of doing this.

Comment: Surely just `class LoginExecutor implements Executor<LoginForm>`?

Comment: What about Request<T> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically if you know the types of the generic you can just do the following:

```
public LoginExecutor implements Executor<LoginForm>
{
   public Result execute(LoginForm request) {...}
}
```

as the name suggests this approach is used for generic programming. When the type is know and you want to use for a particular type, you just implement using the type and from generic it becomes specific.